# MySQL query with GROUP BY on a full text index is very slow

Tags: mysql, select

I'm building an online tool for collecting feedback.
Right now I'm building a visual summary of all answers per question with answer occurence next to it. I use this query:

```
SELECT 
feedback_answer, 
feedback_qtype, 
COUNT(feedback_answer) as occurence 
FROM acc_data_1005 
WHERE (feedback_qtype=5 or feedback_qtype=4 or feedback_qtype=12 or feedback_qtype=13 or feedback_qtype=1 or feedback_qtype=2) 
and survey_id=205283 
GROUP BY feedback_answer ORDER BY feedback_qtype DESC, COUNT(feedback_answer) DESC
```

DB table:

```
CREATE TABLE `acc_data_1005` (
  `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `survey_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `feedback_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `date_registered` date NOT NULL,
  `feedback_qid` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `feedback_question` varchar(140) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `feedback_qtype` tinyint UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'nps, text, input etc',
  `data_type` tinyint UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '0 till 10 are sensitive data options (first name, last name, email etc.)',
  `feedback_answer` varchar(1500) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `additional_data` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

ALTER TABLE `acc_data_1005`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `date_registered` (`date_registered`),
  ADD KEY `feedback_qid` (`feedback_qid`,`feedback_question`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `feedback_id` (`feedback_id`),
  ADD KEY `survey_id` (`survey_id`);
ALTER TABLE `acc_data_1005` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `feedback_answer` (`feedback_answer`);


ALTER TABLE `acc_data_1005`
  MODIFY `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2020001;
COMMIT;
```

The table has around 2 million rows and for this test, they all have the same survey_id.
Profling says executing takes up 96% of time, explain result:

```
id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra

1
SIMPLE
acc_data_1005
NULL
ref
survey_id,feedback_answer
survey_id
4
const
998375
46.86
Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

This query takes around 22-30 seconds for just 11 rows.
If I remove the survey_id (which is important), the query takes around 2-4 seconds (still way too much).

I've been at it for hours but can't find why this query is so slow.
If it helps I can dump the rows in a SQL file (around 400-600MB).

Comment: Fulltext is not used in your query, so fulltext index existence cannot affect the query speed.

Comment: Replace your ORed conditions chain with single `feedback_qtype IN ({values list})`.

Comment: Hi Akina, feedback_answer (the full text index) is used according to the explain results? Replaced OR's with IN, no results

Comment: I see `key = 'survey_id'` which is `ADD KEY `survey_id` (`survey_id`)` in DDL is used. It is not FTS. `feedback_answer` is listed in `possible_keys` but it is not used.

Comment: Ah where can you see that it's actually used/not used? And what is DDL and FTS (Fulltext search?). Any other ideas on how to make the query quicker?

Comment: *where can you see that it's actually used/not used?* ??? You provide query's EXPLAIN - I look at the values of its columns in it. *what is DDL* [Data Definition Language](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-data-definition-statements.html).

Comment: survey_id is not full text I know. feedback_answer however is fulltext and is in possible_keys. Making a GROUP BY on feedback_answer is one of the bottleknecks. Any idea to make that GROUP BY faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group by is slow because of scanning 2 million rows on a fulltext index (feedback_answer) long character items.

I created another table "analytic_stats" and create a cron job that runs this query every month (for only the data of that month) and store that in the stats table.

When the customer want's to get the data of a full year (2 million+ rows, which is too slow) I just get the data of a few rows from the stats table and run the group by query only for the current month. This would just have to group around 10.000-20.000 rows instead of 2 million which is instant.

Maybe not the most efficent way, but it works for me ;)
Hope it might help someone with a similar problem.